# Menu didn't show in Drupal7 multilingual website

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, translation, drupal-modules

I'm making a drupal7 website and I've add French language.

I used MULTILINGUAL - INTERNATIONALIZATION with "Menu translation" :

- Main menu (french) is set as "Fixed Language" : French
- main menu (english) is set as "Fixed Language" : English
- I add a "Translation set" and I set the 2 menu above on it.

When I select the FR language, the menu show the french menu (OK)
When I select the EN language, no menu shown

(there are elements in both menu's :-) )

Is there anybody that can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

had so many problems with that to realize that nodes were not set to the good language, not only the menu items.

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. I just created a basic page in FR and translate it in english. When I show the english page, no menu ... again :-/ but thanks, it was a good idea

Comment: can you send me a link to your site ?